# How to get original email from inline reply or new reply window in Outlook? C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing custom button, if user clicks on it while replying to an email; it would send the email and move the original email to another folder.

My question is how can I get the original email to which user is replying from inline reply or new reply window? I am aware of `GetConversation()` method but it returns all emails. I only want the email to which user is replying.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the inline reply visible in Outlook (`Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse != null`), the currently selected item is the original one (`Explorer.Selection[1]`).

For a message visible in an Inspector, your only choice is to track messages selected in Outlook (`Explorer.SelectionChange`), set up event sinks on the selected items (release the previously selected ones) and track the `MailItem.Reply/ReplyAll/Forward` events (keep in mind that "Forward as Attachment" event is not exposed by OOM).

Comment: Hi @Dmitry thanks for your reply. I am new to Outlook development, don't know really know how to track `Explorer.SelectionChange` and `MailItem.Reply\ReplyAll` Would you be kind enough and provide code for it? Thanks.

Comment: You retrieve the Explorer object from Application.ActiveExplorer and set up event handlers on it. You might also want to track Application.Explorers.NewExplorer event in case new Explorers are opened.